# node.js correct extending of json objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, exchangewebservices

I'm currently using node-ews in a project to access an Exchange Web Server via node.js. Now i ran into a weird problem. To run for example a "CreateItem" request, which can be an E-Mail or Appointment for example, I'm giving the function the arguments as a json similar to this

```
var args = {
    "attributes" : {
        "SendMeetingInvitations" : "SendToAllAndSaveCopy"
    },
    "SavedItemFolderId": {
        "DistinguishedFolderId": {
            "attributes": {
                "Id": "calendar"
            }
        }
    },
    "Items" : {
        "CalendarItem" : {
            "Subject" : "",
            "Body" : {
                "attributes" : {
                },
                "$value" : ""
            },
            "ReminderIsSet" : "true",
            "ReminderMinutesBeforeStart" : "30",
            "Start" : "",
            "End" : "",
            "IsAllDayEvent" : "false",
            "LegacyFreeBusyStatus" : "Busy",
            "Location" : ""
        }
    }
};
```

As the REST-API I'm writing will receive Attributes like Subject, Start, End etc. I initially stripped out those out of the JSON and would define them later like

```
args.Items.CalendarItem.Subject = req.body.Subject;
```

Oddly this will make the internal validation of node-ews fail and tell me that CalendarItem has an invalid Child Subject. If i leave Subject als an empty string in the initial args and later change it set it to req.body.Subject it works just fine.

My question is this: Is the Object somewhat different if I later add attributes and if yes is there a way to do it right? Because I don't think its the best way to have a bunch of empty Attributes in my Object if they aren't used and define standard values for all of them even if api won't require them to be sent.

Would great if someone knew the answer. Hope i could clarify what the problem is

Comment: There may be a way to do this right but you posted no code of how you did it, only the code that was working. If you have a relatively new nodejs and Chrome browser you could try and debug that part of the code. Inspect what req.body.Subject is. You can start node with inspect and break: `node --inspect --debug-brk ./myscript.js` Then open chrome and navigate to `about:inspect` then click on the link: `Open dedicated DevTools for Node` That should take you to the first line of your code. Near the problematic code you can add a `debugger;` statement so it'll pause there.

Comment: req.body.Subject is a regular String. The funny thing is just that it works when I overwrite args.Items.CalendarItem.Subject, but it doesn't if args.Items.CalendarItem.Subject does not exist yet. I'll try to bit more of inspecting today. Will post if I find out something but at the moment I'm pretty clueless

Comment: You could try: `Subject: req.body.Subject || ""` maybe `undefined` is not allowed

Comment: Subject is already never sent to validation as undefined. It's the same string, weather if set with args and overwritten later or defined after args. What I also want to check if there are maybe different encodings for strings and different types are used weather you define it with args oder later

Comment: Did you try to debug? It should pause on the exception (maybe pause on caught exceptions). The stack might show where it goes wrong and why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

so the problem seems to be this. Internally the JSON "object" seems to have an order based on the order the variable is defined. in JavaScript this is no problem. But when the xml is parsed, the tag that was defined last will also be at the end of the xml so if you had

```
   <someTag>
     <variable2 />
     <variable3 />
   </someTag>
```

and you add variable1 to your json by someTag.variable1 = x in the end the xml will look like this after beeing parsed by node-ews

```
   <someTag>
     <variable2 />
     <variable3 />
     <variable1 >x</variable1>
   </someTag>
```

Now unfortunately the exchange web server seems to be picky about the order of the xml tags. so when you build your json be sure to use the direct order. Changing content of the json later will not affect the order.